# Help relating thrust to angular velocity of helicopter in hover

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering

Given a system consisting of an engine and propeller, I want to determine the maximum thrust it will produce when in stationary hover (no forward velocity) above the ground, and what angular velocity the engine shaft must output to achieve this.

Since I would know the watt output of the motor and radius of the blade, I can determine the maximum thrust through the momentum theory equation
$$P=\sqrt{\frac{T^{3}}{2\rho A}}$$

But I've been having trouble finding another simple equation explaining the necessary angular velocity to produce this thrust, **that's where I need your help.**

My best attempt at an equation like this comes from [this paper on blade element theory](https://studylib.net/doc/5869199/blade-element-theory-for-rotor-in-hover-and-climb). As of my knowledge of BET, it treats a blade like several sections which it integrates over to find lift. Since the equation I want need only be a rough approximation, ill assume many things to be constant across the blade in order to collapse the integral.

Sparing you my whole derivation, ill just note that in my example there is no climb velocity and no induced airflow, so I assumed $\phi$ to be $0$, and let the angle of attack be the pitch angle. Finally, by treating the blade I'm working with as an ideally twisted rotor, I arrived at the equation:

$$T=\frac{1}{4}abc\rho \Omega^{2}\theta_{t}R^{3}$$

Where $a$ is the lift curve slope, $b$ is the blade number, $c$ is the chord length, $\rho$ is the density of air, $\Omega$ is the angular velocity, $\theta_{t}$ is the blade tip pitch angle, and $R$ is the blade radius.

Dimensionally, it checks out, but that doesn't mean its necessarily correct. While the approximation may be rough, is it at least correct?

Comment: Isn’t the idea that the thrust or amount of air moved must equal - well exceed due to losses - the mass of the craft?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes. the force of thrust produced by the setup must equal/exceed the force of gravity exerted on the craft. My question is aimed at determining the rotational velocity the setup must reach in order to achieve said level of thrust.

Comment: On the one hand, I know that aerodynamics is hard, and after decades of studying it from an aviation modeler's perspective I'm still nothing resembling an expert.  Based on that I don't believe there's a simple *universal* equation for what you want.  On the other hand, people have been flying helicopters operationally since the mid 1940's (both Germany and the US had some helicopters operating in combat areas during World War II).  Given that, as a species, we have 80 years of experience with this there have to be design handbooks out there with simplified math.